# How to parse xml data in retrofit2 and SimpleXmlConverterFactory?

Tags: android, xml, retrofit, retrofit2, simple-framework

I wonder How to resolve class="array" in XML. Please Help me!!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RFC30>
    <code type="string">000</code>
    <msg type="string">OK</msg>
    <routeList class="array">
        <list class="object">
            <reMark type="string"/>
            <searchFld type="string"/>
            <searchNm type="string"/>
            <stopId type="string">30693</stopId>
            <stopKname type="string">BYC</stopKname>
            <stopStandardid type="string">312100693</stopStandardid>
            <stopX type="string">127.00796999</stopX>
            <stopY type="string">35.82071324</stopY>
        </list>
        <list class="object">
            <reMark type="string"/>
            <searchFld type="string"/>
            <searchNm type="string"/>
            <stopId type="string">30690</stopId>
            <stopKname type="string">BYC</stopKname>
            <stopStandardid type="string">312100690</stopStandardid>
            <stopX type="string">127.00778106</stopX>
            <stopY type="string">35.82043092</stopY>
        </list>
        <list class="object">
            <reMark type="string"/>
            <searchFld type="string"/>
            <searchNm type="string"/>
            <stopId type="string">30683</stopId>
            <stopKname type="string">CTS전북방송</stopKname>
            <stopStandardid type="string">305100683</stopStandardid>
            <stopX type="string">127.14640711</stopX>
            <stopY type="string">35.8199967</stopY>
        </list>
    </routeList>
</RFC30>
```

This is XML data.

**BusStopListInfo.class**

```
Root(name = "RFC30")
public class BusStopListInfo {
    @Element(name = "code")
    private String code;
    @Element(name = "msg")
    private String msg;
    @ElementList(inline = true)
    private ArrayList<BusStopList> routeList;
}
```

**BusStopList.class**

```
@Root(name = "routeList")
public class BusStopList {
    @Element(name = "list")
    private BusStopData list;
}
```

**BusStopData.class**

```
@Root(name = "list")
public class BusStopData {

    @Element(name = "reMark")
    private String reMark;
    @Element(name = "searchFld")
    private String searchFld;
    @Element(name = "searchNm")
    private String searchNm;
    @Element(name = "stopId")
    private String stopId;
    @Element(name = "stopKname")
    private String stopKname;
    @Element(name = "stopStandardId")
    private String stopStandardid;
    @Element(name = "stopX")
    private String stopX;
    @Element(name = "stopY")
    private String stopY;
}
```

But, Error is ..

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                               Process: com.example.mkr.jeonju_bus, PID: 29458
>                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't
>   find class "array" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.mkr.jeonju_bus-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.mkr.jeonju_bus-2/lib/arm,
>   /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>                                                                                   at
>   retrofit2.converter.simplexml.SimpleXmlResponseBodyConverter.convert(SimpleXmlResponseBodyConverter.java:44)
>                                                                                   at
>   retrofit2.converter.simplexml.SimpleXmlResponseBodyConverter.convert(SimpleXmlResponseBodyConverter.java:23)
>                                                                                   at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.toResponse(ServiceMethod.java:119)
>                                                                                   at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:218)
>                                                                                   at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:180)
>                                                                                   at
>   retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.CallExecuteObservable.subscribeActual(CallExecuteObservable.java:41)
>                                                                                   at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10179)
>                                                                                   at
>   retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable.subscribeActual(BodyObservable.java:34)
>                                                                                   at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10179)
>                                                                                   at
>   io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSingleMaybe.subscribeActual(ObservableSingleMaybe.java:30)
>                                                                                   at io.reactivex.Maybe.subscribe(Maybe.java:3540)
>                                                                                   at
>   io.reactivex.internal.operators.maybe.MaybeSubscribeOn$SubscribeTask.run(MaybeSubscribeOn.java:54)
>                                                                                   at io.reactivex.Scheduler$1.run(Scheduler.java:134)
>                                                                                   at
>   io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:59)
>                                                                                   at
>   io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:51)
>                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                                                                                   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:154)
>                                                                                   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:269)
>                                                                                   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
>                                                                                   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "array"
>   on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.mkr.jeonju_bus-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.mkr.jeonju_bus-2/lib/arm,
>   /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>                                                                                   at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
>                                                                                   at org.simpleframework.xml.strategy.Loader.load(Loader.java:50)
>                                                                                   at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.strategy.TreeStrategy.readValue(TreeStrategy.java:163)
>                                                                                   at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.strategy.TreeStrategy.read(TreeStrategy.java:102)
>                                                                                   at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Source.getOverride(Source.java:360)
>                                                                                   at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.Factory.getConversion(Factory.java:207)
>                                                                                   at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Factory.getOverride(Factory.java:139)
>                                                                                   at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.ObjectFactory.getInstance(ObjectFactory.java:63)
>                                                                                   at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read(Composite.java:139)
>                                                                                   at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Traverser.read(Traverser.java:92)
>                                                                                   at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.CompositeInlineList.read(CompositeInlineList.java:190)
>                                                                                   at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.CompositeInlineList.read(CompositeInlineList.java:167)
>                                                                                   at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.CompositeInlineList.read(CompositeInlineList.java:124)
>                                                                                   at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readVariable(Composite.java:623)
>                                                                                   at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readInstance(Composite.java:573)
>                                                                                   at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readUnion(Composite.java:549)
>                                                                                   at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readElement(Composite.java:532)
>                                                                                   at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readElements(Composite.java:445)
>                                                                                   at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.access$400(Composite.java:59)
>                                                                                   at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite$Builder.read(Composite.java:1383)
>                                                                                   at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read(Composite.java:201)
>                                                                                 at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your XML defines a `class` attribute, which SimpleXML would use to determine an exact class type for what it is reading. Obviously no class called `array` exists, so it fails with an exception.

However, `Persister` class can be initialized with a `Strategy` in constructor, and you could for example use `AnnotationStrategy` so that it ignores `class=` attribute, and checks against `@Convert()` annotation instead.

See [@Convert](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/convert/Convert.html), [AnnotationStrategy](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/convert/AnnotationStrategy.html), [Strategy](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/strategy/Strategy.html) and [Persister](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/core/Persister.html#Persister(org.simpleframework.xml.strategy.Strategy)).

In your case, you will most likely need to write your own custom strategy, see the default [TreeStrategy.read()](https://github.com/ngallagher/simplexml/blob/cff0578c32ca27b7e76f3098988990f674a4e31c/src/main/java/org/simpleframework/xml/strategy/TreeStrategy.java#L101-L112) as an example.

Comment: Sorry, I can not understand. Could you show me the example?

Comment: I tried to use .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.createNonStrict(
                        new Persister(new AnnotationStrategy())
                ))    but I don't know how to use @Convert.. any more. Sorry

Comment: Okay, so the default strategy is `TreeStrategy` as you can see in [here](https://github.com/ngallagher/simplexml/blob/cff0578c32ca27b7e76f3098988990f674a4e31c/src/main/java/org/simpleframework/xml/core/Persister.java#L227), so the problem is this [readValue](https://github.com/ngallagher/simplexml/blob/cff0578c32ca27b7e76f3098988990f674a4e31c/src/main/java/org/simpleframework/xml/strategy/TreeStrategy.java#L163) method, you must override `read` so that if the `class` node is `array` then it will `return readArray`:

Comment: You can see the implementation for `read()` that you need to basically copy over to your own custom strategy, [**here**](https://github.com/ngallagher/simplexml/blob/cff0578c32ca27b7e76f3098988990f674a4e31c/src/main/java/org/simpleframework/xml/strategy/TreeStrategy.java#L101-L112)

Comment: **@Root(name = "routeList", strict = false)

public class BusStopList extends TreeStrategy{


    @Element(name = "list")

    private BusStopData list;



    @Override

    public Value read(Type type, NodeMap node, Map map) throws Exception {
        return super.read(type, node, map);
    }
}**


is this way..?? I'm stupid.. I didn't understand not at all.
I think that i have to define class attribute. but i don't know well...